# How to upload file using jquery and Web API

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload a file from jQuery and web api. If I upload only file, it works. If I add some more data to it, it do not work. Below is the code;
JQuery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button1").click(OnUpload);
        });

        function OnUpload(evt) {
            //var files = $("#file1").get(0).files;
            var request = {
                Name: "test",
                Address: "address",
                Description: "desc",
                City: "city",
                files:$("#file1").get(0).files
            };

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(request);

            if (files.length > 0) {
                if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                    var data = new FormData();
                    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        data.append("file" + i, files[i]);
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost:51801/api/FileUpload/",
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: jsonData + files,
                        success: function (results) {
                            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                alert(results[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 multiple file uploads!");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

C# Web API code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(RequestP req)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var docfiles = new List<string>();
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    docfiles.Add(filePath);
                }
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);
            }
            else
            {
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

public class RequestP
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public List<HttpPostedFileBase> files { get; set; }
    }
```

Passing HttpPostedFileBase from MVC controller to ApiController will also help.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497944/file-upload-jquery-webapi

Comment: In controller method, how to access other form data ?

Comment: I can't see that you are sending formData

Comment: Please check request object. I am trying to send files to be uploaded and some other fields as well.

Comment: Please down vote carefully, the reference question is partially answered.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I am answering late, but maybe this will help someone else with your problem.

This is what worked for me:

Html file/Mvc View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<label for="txtFile">Upload file: </label>
<input type="file" id="txtFile" name="file" />
<br />
<a href="#" id="lnkUploadFile">Upload File</a>

<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        var $txtFile = $('#txtFile'),
            files;
        var data = new FormData();
        $('#lnkUploadFile').click(function ()
        {
            uploadFile();
        });

        function uploadFile()
        {
            if ($txtFile.length)
            {
                files = $txtFile[0].files;
                data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
                data.append("ImageName", 'MyImage');
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/FileUpload/",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data
            }).then(function () { });
        }


    });

</script>
```

Web Api Controller:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class FileUploadController : ApiController
    {
        // POST api/fileupload
        public void Post()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
            {
                // Get the uploaded image from the Files collection
                var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedImage"];

                if (httpPostedFile != null)
                {
                    // Get the complete file path
                    String fileSavePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/") + HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["ImageName"].ToString();

                    // Save the uploaded file to "UploadedFiles" folder
                    httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.